# How to split sentence in visual c++?

Tags: string, split, c++-cli

Hi I'm currently using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, c++ with forms and having trouble with split. I have tried many code exemples (all of them was on console application and I didn't know how to make them work for me). This is how at least I imagining code (simplified code exemple below). There is a string that you take from textBox1, then you split that string where there is a dot, and putting them in table.

```
String ^ text = textBox1->Text;
text->ToString()->Split('.');
tableGrid->Rows[0]->Cells[1]->Value = text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Split` does not modify `text` here. Instead it returns an array of the split results.

You need to capture and use the results so something like this:

```
String^ text = textBox1->Text;
cli::array<String^>^ pieces = text->Split('.');
for (int i = 0; i < pieces->Length; ++i) {
    // Add pieces[i] to the table. Perhaps:
    tableGrid->Rows[0]->Cells[i]->Value = pieces[i];

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you suggest which way is best to put each pieces in separate rows ?

Comment: It's hard to be specific without knowing the exact type of the table but I'll assume it's DataGrid.  If so, you would want to start learning here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/keb37h7b(v=vs.100).aspx and convert to C++/CLI